# relationship between references and objects in an inheritance scenario

Tags: java

In Java, how is an object reference related to the instance it refers
to?
     I have run into something really tricky and would like to have a deep understanding of it. In the following scenario, the shine() of the subclass overrides that of the superclass(which is normal), but the name property is that of the superclass despite NEW was called on the subclass (which i find weird!) Would someone help me understand this?

```
class Father {
    public String name = "John Senior";
    public void shine() {
        System.out.println(name + "'s shining");
    }
}

//Subclass
class Son extends Father {
    public String name = "John Junior";
    public void shine() {
        System.out.println(name + "'s shining");
    }
}

//Demo Class
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Father f1 = new Son();
        System.out.println(f1.name);
        f1.shine();
    }
}

//program output

/*John Senior
John Junior's shining */
```

Comment: This code wouldn't compile. There's no `s1` in `main`. Also post the output.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar you are right. it was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are not polymorphic in Java; they do not override one another.  Whereas methods are polymorphic. Hence the above behavior. 
If you want to print super class member, use `super` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you observe may be not intuitive at first, but it actually is, because as @shaggy-d mentioned, variables are not polymorphic. Let me explain a little bit, what is happening, but first of all forget about the `shine()` method and let us understand `name` first.

Here are some other examples on your `main` method, with the appropriate output and an explanation:

Example 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object f1 = new Son();
    System.out.println(Father.class.cast(f1).name);
    System.out.println(Son.class.cast(f1).name);
}
```

Output:

```
John Senior
John Junior
```

You actually hide the type of the `f1` variable and say `Hi Java let's treat at within the scope as`Object`. So now when you want to get the`name`, you actually need to tell Java what it should think of the object, i.e., is it a`Father`or a`Son`. Depending on your decision, Java picks what`name`-attribute to use.

Example 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Son f1 = new Son();
    System.out.println(Father.class.cast(f1).name);
    System.out.println(Son.class.cast(f1).name);
    System.out.println(f1.name);
}
```

Output:

```
John Senior
John Junior
John Junior
```

As expected, when you tell Java that the object should be treated as `Son` within your scope, it resolves the `name` from son (if not explicitly casted otherwise.

Now getting back to your `shine()` method. Again as @shaggy-d mentioned, methods are polymorph. Thus, when calling a method of an object, Java determines the "lowest" available implementation within the object hierarchy and executes that method.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I'll try to explain it with a diagram: when we instantiate `Son` there's an instance of `Father` which is created as well, it is created: under the hood,  before Son's constructor is called - Father's constructor is called as well, so the new instance of `Son` has also the context of an object from the class it extends.

Now, since you declared `F1` as type `Father`, when `f1.name` is evaluated, it is being looked up in the context of `Father` - and that's how we're getting "senior".

But when the method is called, polymorphism "kicks in" and the method that is called is the one that belongs to `Son` (and which overrides the `Father`'s method). This is happening because we assigned a `new Son()` to `f1`.

Comment: Thanks for this clean explanation. I wanted the confirmation that the no-arg constructor of  Father is implicitly called anytime we create an instance of Son.